# How to WhatsApp Call without saving number manually

Tags: android

I am trying to write a code to whatsapp call a mobile number, without saving it to the phonebook.
I have written the code as:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
callIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.whatsapp", "com.whatsapp.Conversation"));
callIntent.putExtra("jid", "19876543210@s.whatsapp.net");//phone number without "+" prefix
callIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "voip-call");
callIntent.putExtra("call", true);
callIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
startActivity(callIntent);
```

But it is not working.
Any sort of help would be beneficial for my learning.

Comment: please add error logs